# How to add a 'frame' image (png) without losing interactivity

Tags: html, css, png

I'd like to add a png frame over a kwicks image slider, but when I do, I lose the interactivity.

How can I add a png frame over an element without losing the interactivity of the element below?

You can see the example here: www.jujumamablog.com/jujumama/dev.html

Below is the code for the dev page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <title>Kwicks Examples: Example 1</title>
        <script src="http://jmar777.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jmar777.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="http://kwicks.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v1.5.1/Kwicks/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <style type="text/css">

        /* defaults for all examples */
        .kwicks {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .kwicks li{
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* example 1 */
        #example1 .kwicks li{
            float: left;
            width: 96px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-right: 2px;
        }
        #example1 #kwick1 { 
            background-color: #53b388;
        }
        #example1 #kwick2 {
            background-color: #5a69a9;
        }
        #example1 #kwick3 {
            background-color: #c26468;
        }
        #example1 #kwick4 { 
            background-color: #bf7cc7;
        }
        #example1 #kwick5 { 
            background-color: #bf7cc7;
            margin-right: none;
        }
        #sliderFrame{
            background: transparent url('sliderFrame.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
            display: block;
            height: 206px;
            position: absolute;
        //  top: 150px;
            width: 504px;
            z-index: 99;
            margin-top: -4px;

        }
        </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
            $('.kwicks').kwicks({
                max : 205,
                spacing : 5
            });
        });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

            <div id="example1">
            <div id="sliderFrame"></div> <!-- This blocks ineteractivity -->
                <ul class="kwicks">

                    <li id="kwick1"></li>
                    <li id="kwick2"></li>
                    <li id="kwick3"></li>
                    <li id="kwick4"></li>
                    <li id="kwick5"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>

            <div id="example1">
                <ul class="kwicks">

                    <li id="kwick1"></li>
                    <li id="kwick2"></li>
                    <li id="kwick3"></li>
                    <li id="kwick4"></li>
                    <li id="kwick5"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately using z-index to 'layer' elements will cause the below elements to become non-interactive, but they are still obviously visible.

Therefore, there's two options here:

1. **JavaScript** - much like the coloured boxes below (layer 1), place a further element (layer 3) over the 'rounded corners' image (layer 2) but making the background-color: transparent for those interactable boxes, then referencing the JavaScript to move the 1st layer boxes as well as the 3rd layer boxes.
2. **CSS** - slice the rounded corner image to be used within those interactive boxes, and use them as background images. This would be a fair amount of work, trial and error to get it right but would mean no extra javascript or messing around with z-index.

Hope that helps, and doesn't confuse matters further :)

Comment: Good answers man!  I had just completed slicing and implementing that (successfully) when I refreshed the page to see your comment.  I had thought about the 3rd layer of JS, but I'm not confident enough with it yet to be able to do that quickly.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I think the CSS approach would be much easier anyway, as you won't run into problems with z-index in older browsers, let us know if it all works out!

Answer (score 1):

You can't place one element over another and retain the lower-level's interactivity. At least, not without using Javascript; and I can't think of a plugin or script that achieves what you want.

Could you use the image as some form of background for the element for which you want to retain the functionality?

Comment: I'm shooting for that rounded corners look, I thought this would be a relatively easy way to achieve that.